# DB2 Delete With Inner Join

Tags: sql, db2, inner-join, sql-delete

I have a query like this :

```
DELETE FROM db2inst1.REPORTER_STATUS INNER JOIN REPORTER_DETAILS 
ON REPORTER_STATUS.SERVERSERIAL = REPORTER_DETAILS.SERVERSERIAL 
AND year(REPORTER_STATUS.FIRSTOCCURRENCE)=2011 AND 
month(REPORTER_STATUS.FIRSTOCCURRENCE)=12 AND 
day(REPORTER_STATUS.FIRSTOCCURRENCE)=12
```

I want to run a query like tihs but it gives me error. How can i run a query like that ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Beyond that, why are you separating the date/time information?  That's going to cause your query to ignore indices (be slow).  Use a range query like `AND Reporter_Status.firstOccurrence >= DATE('2011-12-12') AND Reporter_Status.firstOccurrence < DATE('2011-12-12') + 1 DAY`, which'll be able to use an index (and doesn't about the exact type of that column).

Comment: i'm parsing hours inside of it adn i got lots of dates before this query so i have to do something like that.

Comment: @Rahul it doesn't run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether the posted form of delete (`DELETE` with `JOINS`) is allowed in DB2 but you can try doing like below

```
DELETE FROM REPORTER_STATUS 
WHERE year(REPORTER_STATUS.FIRSTOCCURRENCE)=2011 
AND month(REPORTER_STATUS.FIRSTOCCURRENCE)=12 
AND day(REPORTER_STATUS.FIRSTOCCURRENCE)=12
AND SERVERSERIAL in 
(
SELECT distinct SERVERSERIAL from REPORTER_DETAILS
)
```

Comment: I want to remove from REPORTER_DETAILS table

Comment: @developerCoder, your post says you want to delete from `REPORTER_STATUS` table. Anyways, you just need to change the table reference accordingly.